# Recursive bash script: how to modify function parameter on recursive calls

Tags: bash, recursion

I'm trying to reverse a string in bash using a recursive algorithm.

```
func:
    if string is length 1 or 0
        return string
    else 
        return concatenation of last letter + func(the other letters)
```

here is my reverse function:

```
reverse () {

    if [[ ${#1} -le 1 ]]
    then
        echo $1
    else
        tail=${1: (-1)}
        length=${#1}
        rest=${1:0:((length-1))}
        echo "${tail}""${reverse rest}"
    fi
}
```

I'm getting `${reverse rest}: bad substitution` so I assume there's an issue with the way I'm passing the parameter to the recursive function call.

Any thoughts on this? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is `main` a typo for `reverse`?  That's not how you would make a recursive call: you would need something like `echo "$tail $(reverse "$rest")"`.

Comment: But in any case, this isn't the kind of thing you write a shell script for. Use a shell script for managing *other* programs that manipulate data, not for manipulating data directly.

Comment: @chepner yes `main` is a typo, sorry. And thanks, I was just following along with the Bash exercises on [Exercism](https://exercism.io/tracks/bash), one of which being a reverse string exercise. I'm new to bash so I thought I'd try a recursive algorithm, which, though unnecessary, let's me explore various elements of the language.

Comment: It's more important to explore the features in a context where they will be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something like :

```
reverse(){
    local arg=$1
    test ${#arg} -le 1 && echo "$arg" || echo "${arg: -1}$(reverse "${arg:0:-1}")"
}
```